# rails run function inside query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have the following query, is it possible to be able to run a function inside? Let's say I want to add `WHERE zip_code = user_distance(zip_code)`?

I want to take data from each row and run it through a function before actually selecting it.

```
@posts = Listing.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM listings WHERE industry = ? && ", current_user.industry])
```

Comment: You want to run it through a _ruby_ function before you select it?

Comment: Yeah --  what i'm trying to do is pull a zip code from `Listing` and calculate the distance between that zip code and the user set zip code (I have a function for that) and if it's less than the user set 'max_distance' then select the listing row. There might be a better way to do this outside of SQL, not sure, I'm really new to rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mainly looking to get this working and not worrying so much about performance (because going straight to the SQL is faster than going through ActiveRecord) then you could do:

```
listings = []
Listing.all.each do |listing|
    listings << listing if user_distance(listing.zip_code)
end
```

So, it will go through each listing and add it to that array if the `user_distance` method returns true (or however it is set up).

Another thing you could do is set up a stored procedure ("stored proc") on your database that takes in a zip code and returns what it is you want (i.e, does the same thing as `user_distance`), and that user defined variable `max_distance` could be in a database table so it's accessible to your stored procedure. Then you could call that stored proc from the SQL and still be able to pass in the zip_code of each row.